# Appending a property to each object in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, object

I'm using Node.js and Mongoose to access a MongoDB database and return an array of objects from a MongoDB collection. However, I want to append a property to each of the returned objects. My code is shown below

```
router.get('/admin/manage_accounts/view_all', (req,res) => {
    Community_Member.find({}, (error, community_member) => {
        community_member.forEach(function(element){
            element.Role = "Community Member"
        })
        
        console.log(community_member)
        res.send(community_member)
     })
}
```

The objects from the database are returned, but the Role property is not appended to any of the objects and I'm not certain why. Can anyone give me a bit of insight?

Comment: Do you have the same issue with `element["Role"] = "Community Member"`?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I do.

Answer (score 1):

The standard functional way to do it is by using `map`

```
router.get('/admin/manage_accounts/view_all', (req,res) => {
    Community_Member.find({}, (error, community_member) => {
        community_member = community_member.map(element => {
            element.Role = "Community Member"
            return element
        })
        
        console.log(community_member)
        res.send(community_member)
     })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, this does not produce the desired output. The Role property still isn't appended to each object.